# Too many first_value in query?

Tags: database, oracle, date, join, window-functions

I want to get the first invoice by its date of every po_distribution_id and its data:

```
SELECT UNIQUE 
first_value(i.invoice_id) OVER (PARTITION BY po_distribution_id ORDER BY i.invoice_date asc) invoice_id
,first_value(i.invoice_date) OVER (PARTITION BY po_distribution_id ORDER BY i.invoice_date asc) invoice_date
,first_value(i.invoice_num) OVER (PARTITION BY po_distribution_id ORDER BY i.invoice_date asc) invoice_date
FROM AP_INVOICE_DISTRIBUTIONS_ALL d LEFT JOIN ap_invoices_all i on d.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
WHERE sysdate - i.invoice_date < 30
ORDER BY invoice_id DESC
```

Wonder if there is a better way of accomplishing this without using so many first_value. The query is not slow, but I feel uneasy with it.

Example:

```
po_distribution_id  invoice_id  invoice_date
212121              2212        2019-05-05
212121              2355        2019-01-09
212121              1122        2019-02-02
212121              7744        2019-03-04
```

Should return:

```
po_distribution_id  invoice_id  invoice_date
212121              2355        2019-01-09
```

Comment: row number over in a subquery, where rn = 1 in the outer

Comment: hang on a mo.. why are you changing the ordering of the partitions? this might as well be a group by/min

Comment: perhaps you should tell us what you have, and what you want, rather than giving us a query that might not be broken and asking us to guess an equivalent query without knowing anything about the data it processes..

Comment: @CaiusJard added!

Comment: @GabrielA.Zorrilla: your sample data and results is missing column `invoice_num`, which seems like an important information here.

Comment: @GMB no, it's always sorted by invoice_date. The sorting by invoice_num was removed in my last edit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All three `first_value()` functions use the same partition but the last one has a different ordering (`invoice_date`, vs `invoice_num` in the first two). *If* the ordering of `invoice_num` and `invoice_date` are the same, then you can use `row_number()` in a subquery, and filter in the outer query:

```
select *
from (
    select 
        i.invoice_id,
        i.invoice_date,
        i.invoice_num,
        row_number() over(partition by po_distribution_id order by i.invoice_num) rn
    from 
        ap_invoice_distributions_all d 
        left join ap_invoices_all i on d.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
    where sysdate - i.invoice_date < 30
) x
where rn = 1
```

Comment: except he can't decide whether to order his partition by inv date or inv num.. so I'm no longer sure if it's equivalent even though I commented similar

Comment: @CaiusJard: you are right. We don't know if the ordering is the same on these columns. I edited my answer to specify that this solution only works if the ordering of both columns is the same.

Comment: Cool stuff. There is a typo in row_number()

Comment: based on the recent edit I would advocate `order by invoice_date`

Answer (score 1):

If for each `po_distribution_id`, the invoice dates are all distinct (if they aren't, the question doesn't make much sense in the first place - you must explain how you break the ties), then you don't need analytic functions at all. Aggregate functions (specifically, the `FIRST()` function) can do the job, and much faster.

```
select po_distribution_id, 
       min(invoice_id) keep (dense_rank first order by invoice_date) as invoice_id,
       min(invoice_date) as invoice_date
from   [........]
where  [........]
group  by po_distribution_id
order  by [........]
```